Example of a strictly increasing continuous function differentiable almost everywhere that does not satisfy the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus
I am looking for an example of a function $ f : [0, 1] \to \mathbb{R} $ that satisfies the following properties:

$ f $ is continuous on $ [0, 1] $,
$ f $ is strictly increasing,
$ f $ is differentiable almost everywhere on $ [0, 1] $,

but does not satisfy the equality:
$$
f(x) - f(0) = \int_{0}^{x} f'(t) \, dt.
$$
I understand that the failure of this equality can occur if $f'(t)$ behaves poorly (e.g., jumps on a set of measure zero), but I am struggling to construct an explicit example of such a function.
I have been thinking about the Cantor function or the Volterra function, but neither of them is strictly increasing, so they do not meet the requirements.
Could someone provide an example and explain why this function does not satisfy the equality?
Thank you in advance.

The Cantor function is a good start. Wikipedia says:

Georg Cantor (1884) introduced the Cantor function and mentioned that Scheeffer pointed out that it was a counterexample to an extension of the fundamental theorem of calculus claimed by Harnack.

You'll have to tweak it a bit though - because it is, as you say, not strictcly increasing. If $C(x)$ is the Cantor function, consider $$f: [0,1]\to \mathbb{R}, x\mapsto x+\alpha C(x)$$ where $\alpha>0$.
The Cantor function $C(x)$ is continuous on $[0, 1]$, and thus also $f(x)$.
If $0\leq x_1<x_2\leq 1$, then $$   f(x_2) - f(x_1) = (x_2 - x_1) + \alpha \bigl(C(x_2) - C(x_1)\bigr).
$$ Since $C(x)$ is nondecreasing, we have: $$   f(x_2) - f(x_1) \geq x_2 - x_1 > 0,$$ which means that $f$ is strictly increasing. The Cantor function $C(x)$ is differentiable $C'(x) = 0$ for almost all $x \in [0, 1]$.
However (recall: $C(0)=0$):
$$f(x) - f(0) = \bigl[x + \alpha C(x)\bigr] - \bigl[0 + \alpha C(0)\bigr] = x + \alpha C(x) \neq \int_0^x f'(t) \, dt = x.$$ Remember that $f'(x) = 1  +\alpha C'(x)$ but $C'(x) = 0$ almost everywhere in $[0,1]$.

A slightly different tweak would be to consider $F(x)=x , C(x)$ (strictly increasing and continuous) as the CDF of $\max(X,Y)$ where $X \sim U[0,1]$ and independently $Y$ has a Cantor distribution.  Then $F'(x) = C(x)$ almost everywhere in $[0,1]$ but $\int_{0}^{x} C(t) , dt < F(x)$ when $0<x\le 1$: for example the integral gives $\frac12$ when $x=1$ while $F\left(1\right)=1$, and $\frac16$ when $x=\frac 12$ while $F\left(\frac12\right)=\frac14$, and $\frac2{175}$ when $x=\frac1{10}$ while $F\left(\frac1{10}\right)=\frac1{50}$.
